# Yandex-tank installation error

Tags: debian, apt, yandex-tank

While yandex-tank installation I followed the official documentation https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html doing so:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yandex-load/main
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yandex-load-tank-base
```

But got an error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yandex-load/main/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yandex-load/main/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I guess. that's the reason of error while launching yandex-tank:

```
    17:09:35 INFO: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 224, in configure
    self.core.load_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 243, in load_plugins
    plugin = il.import_module(plugin_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

17:09:35 ERROR: Import by filename is not supported.
```

How to fix the problem?

System: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use Ubuntu repositories in Debian. Package version may conflict and many other things can go wrong.

At your own risk, you can still try to do that. The closest Ubuntu version to Wheezy is 13.10. So first, remove the ppa you just installed:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yandex-load/main
```

and manually add these lines to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yandex-load/main/ubuntu saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yandex-load/main/ubuntu saucy main
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately I've still got that 404 errors. It's weird, because documentation tells about any Debian-based system

Comment: That's impossible. `http://ppa.launchpad.net/yandex-load/main/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages` exists. You must be getting errors from old repositories, meaning you didn't remove PPA properly or didn't do `apt-get update`.

Comment: Yes, first 2 errors based on /yandex-load disappeared, but last 2 still occur

Comment: You need to remove `yannubuntu/boot-repair` ppa too.